# What is the maximum number of downvotes a question can have

Tags: discussion

I was just wondering what the maximum number of down votes a question can have before it is removed from StackOverflow.

Comment: 5 people cast close votes. After that 3 people cast delete votes. No downvotes need to be involved.

Comment: What's the current number of users?

Comment: Well, there's an easy way to find out...

Comment: Be nice, @LBT - be nice

Comment: I never saw a question with more than -9 before it got removed so i thought that might be a limit

Comment: Most likely (2^31)-1 since it's probably stored in a 32 bit signed int field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519990/why-does-i-j-k-j-i-kk-i-j-11, @System.Object. You can sort question by votes.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126919/evaluating-the-risks-of-allowing-teen-moderators-on-the-se-network -90 and not deleted yet.

Comment: @Servy - You **had** to come in with Logic, did you?

Comment: @Oded Well, guesswork, really, not logic.  I don't *know* the details of the implementation.

Comment: Should I upvote the question because I'm also curious, or downvote it because... I'm curious? :D I'm joking, but maybe we should pick up random really bad question and just try if it goes below 99?

Comment: Search for `*`, order by votes and go to the last page @ŁukaszLech -179 on MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/33949#33949 and -148 on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards unfortunately the second is locked and can't get lower ^^

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [the data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) the SCORE column of the POSTS table is an INT.

Stack Exchange uses SQL Server, the [minimum value of an int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) is -2,147,483,648, so this (unless there's a table with a smaller datatype somewhere).

As [Toomai mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186125/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-downvotes-a-question-can-have/186127#comment570830_186127) this is the minimum possible score. As score is upvotes - downvotes the maximum number of downvotes is actually double this (assuming you also got 2,147,483,648 upvotes).

As [TronicZomB points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186125/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-downvotes-a-question-can-have#comment570805_186125) it's also constrained by the number of people with the downvote privilege. The number as of the last dump was [175,988](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/122007/number-of-users-with-the-downvote-privilege) so this was the theoretical maximum on 2013/06/25. It will be higher by now.

Comment: I suspect this would cause a question with a title something like _EEEEEEKKKKK! ScoreOverflow_ though.

Comment: Yeah that's the min possible score, but the question is asking about downvotes, which I guess is either `maxint` or `maxsignedint`.

Comment: It should be double I think @Toomai, I've updated.

Comment: ooh; cool note about the number of users with d/v privs.

Answer (score 3):

If by "removed" you mean removed from the system entirely, there is no number of downvotes that will result in a question being removed. Deletion can be done by the question owner, one moderator, or a group of community members who have enough rep to vote to delete. However deleted questions are not removed and can be seen by members who have enough rep to see deleted questions.

If by "removed" you mean not shown on the front page, it's -9 on Meta and I believe -5 on StackOverflow. See [On Meta, are the rules for showing on the main page different?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180092/on-meta-are-the-rules-for-showing-on-the-main-page-different)

Comment: I guess that answers the question better than my own :-).

Comment: Gotta say I actually like yours better. Is it Friday yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've got at least another 8 hours of meetings to suffer through before Friday comes around :-(.