# How old is data for queries?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I like to play with stack exchange queries sometimes and usually data is outdate. I assumed that SO database is cloned/copied periodically. Just wondering, how old is data?

Comment: It is updated weekly.

Comment: It's updated every Sunday.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a duplicate of a specific "hey, SEDE hasn't been updated in a while" question. The answer there is almost entirely unrelated. (cc @juergend)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data is refreshed weekly (usually on Sundays) and the [front page of SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) tells you the date of the last import:

> [image]

Comment: mmmm 20 million comments that's a lot, but actually from all the fuss then have been causing lately on Meta it's less then I expected. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180082/dealing-with-the-weeds-that-are-comments-on-stack-overflow