# "How frequently is SEDE updated?" wrong on FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, faq-update-request

According to [How old is data for queries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182221/how-old-is-data-for-queries), SEDE's data is updated every Sunday, but the [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq) says:

> **How frequently is Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?**
>
> Data is updated monthly.

This should be corrected.

Comment: I really hope changing the faq doesn't require code base update as this one might take many many more weeks/months/years.

Comment: It also says _"... is hosted on SQL Server 2008 R2"_, which is incorrect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the entire about/FAQ was a bit outdated.

So, I replaced it with [`/help`](https://data.stackexchange.com/help), which has more accurate information about the update times [in the FAQ section](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq). The [SQL Server version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183774/how-frequently-is-sede-updated-wrong-on-faq#comment561158_183774) will be less prone to misinformation now as well.

Comment: Nice job Tim, the help page looks great!

Comment: Don't know if this is just me, but the icons are broken.

Comment: @Asad Yeah, it's a production deployment bug. Will be fixed following some additional cleanup.